# Ubuntu from pendrive

Tags: files, format, support

I have Ubuntu 14.04 in my USB pen drive but when I insert my pen drive in Windows 10 ,it shows invalid file format .I could not find my pen drive in boot options too.

Comment: How'd you create the media?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when making a **bootable USB** is not done properly (usually when done using **PowerISO**)...

Please format that USB. and.. follow the below-given methods to create LiveUSB

- If you are using Windows:

  You can use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)...

  For complete description: [Official Ubuntu Help on creating Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- If you already have an Ubuntu You can use the Startup Disk Creator: [Ubuntu help](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

**Additional information :**

If you created the installation media using the Disks tool, it cannot be readable on Windows.

[image]